# Divide paired matching columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `df` with matching columns that are also paired. The matching columns are defined in the factor `patient`. I would like to devide the matching columns by each other. Any suggestions how to do this?

I tried this, but this does not take the pairing from `patient` into account.

```
m1 <- m1[sort(colnames(df)]
m1_g <- m1[,grep("^n",colnames(df))]
m1_r <- m1[,grep("^t",colnames(df))]
m1_new <- m1_g/m1_r
m1_new



head(df)

                                     na-008 ta-008  nc012   tb012        na020 na-018  ta-018 na020 tc020   tc093   nc093
hsa-let-7b-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGT          56         311      137         242     23    96    113    106    41   114
hsa-let-7b-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGG       208         656      350         713     49   476    183    246   157   306
hsa-let-7b-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGT      631        1978     1531        2470    216  1906    732    850   665   909
hsa-let-7b-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTT    2760        8159     6067        9367    622  4228   2931   3031  2895  2974
hsa-let-7b-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTGTGGTTT   1698        4105     3737        3729    219  1510   1697   1643  1527  1536

> head(patient)
$`008`
[1] "na-008" "ta-008"

$`012`
[1] "nc012" "tb012"

$`018`
[1] "na-018" "ta-018"

$`020`
[1] "na020" "tc020"

$`045`
[1] "nb045" "tc045"

$`080`
[1] "nb-080" "ta-080"
```

Comment: The data you showed seems to be following the paired order.  Can you check if these are not ordered?  Try with `library(gtools);m1 <- m1[mixedsort(colnames(df)]`

Comment: This was just an examples. The columns are not ordered based on pairing

Comment: Have you tried with `mixedsort`

Comment: How does it take the "patient" factor into  account?

Comment: Do you duplicate column names in your original dataset (or is it a typo in the example)?

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo

Comment: Please do update your post.  Because in some cases, there are multiple t column names and no corresponding `n` column.  I guess `m1 <- df[order(as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', names(df))))]` could work

Comment: My doubt is also that is there any chance you have `tc012` column in the dataset along with `tb012` (which is found to paired with `nc012` in the `patient` list

Comment: Based on the `patient` data, you can also do `lst <- lapply(patient, function(x) {x1 <- df[match(x, names(df), nomatch=0)]; if(length(x1)>0) x1[1]/x1[2]}); do.call(cbind,Filter(Negate(is.null), lst))`

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(x1, 2) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Based on the example provided, it is working for me.